Не работает форматер в VS Code для php c HTML
Прошу подсказать, что можно сделать, чтобы нормально форматировать php файлы с html разметкой в VS CODE. Поставил расширение PHP Intelephense - результата нет. Чисто php файл - поправляется как надо, а если внутри есть тэги HTML, то уже нет. Ставил и "phpfmt - PHP formatter" - но он выбрасывает ошибку "phpfmt: Error getting php version".
Вот код файла настройки setting.json
{
    "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
    // "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": "explicit"
    },
    "[vue]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "Vue.volar"
    },
    "[php]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "kokororin.vscode-phpfmt"
    },
    // "[php]": {
    //     "editor.defaultFormatter": "bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client"
    // },
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:/OSPanel/modules/php/PHP_8.1/php.exe",
    // "phpfmt.php_bin": "php",
    // "php.executablePath":  "C:/OSPanel/modules/php/PHP_8.1/php.exe",
}

Закомментированы различные советы из Google).

Тут надо смотреть что именно за html прописан в php в файле и то, как вы хотите чтобы там было "красиво".....  Есть вероятность, что правильная рекомендация будет использовать MVC,  а не html в php.... но это надо смотреть что и как

К сожалению тут сложно в комментариях писать примеры. Дам ссылку на скрин https://clip2net.com/s/4kD1BF8  - Специально сломано, чтоб посмотреть работу.  https://clip2net.com/s/4kD1FaQ - хотелось бы хотя бы так..

А зачем писать в комментариях, если для описания проблемы есть целый блок вопроса?
